# document.fragment

Tags: javascript

Не могу создать фрагмент.
Эту часть кода необходимо записать во фрагмент:

```
var paragraph = window.document.createElement('p'),
author = window.document.createElement('strong'),
time = window.document.createElement('time'),
content = window.document.createElement('div');
```

Я делаю так:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var paragraph = window.document.createElement('p');
var author = window.document.createElement('strong');
var time = window.document.createElement('time');
var content = window.document.createElement('div');
fragment.appendChild(paragraph);
fragment.appendChild(author);
fragment.appendChild(time);
fragment.appendChild(content);
```

Не получается. Что делать с window? Как записать во фрагмент?

Comment: можешь конкретнее проблему описать? код приведенный в вопросе - корректен, и добавляет во фрагмент 4 элемента

Comment: то есть window никак не вдияет в данном случае?

Comment: да, его можно опустить и не писать, `window.document === document`

Comment: что именно _не получается_?

Comment: @GavrenkoKaterina _"Что делать с window?"_ -- ничего. просто не пишите. а если вам надо фрагмент встроить в страницу, то пишете так: `document.body.appendChild(fragment);`

Answer (score 0):

> Не могу создать фрагмент.

Вместо многих вызовов `window.document.createElement` можно добавить значение в свойство `innerHTML`.

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragment.innerHTML = "<p/><strong/><time/><div/>";
```

или, если div, p и strong - это контейнеры для time, то так:

```
fragment.innerHTML = "<div><p><strong><time/></strong></p></div>";
```

---

**UPDATE**

У `DocumentFragment` не работает часть функций, например, `getElementsByTagName`, поэтому проще использовать jquery.

```
// создаем новый тег с подтегами
var f = $("<div><p><strong><time /></strong></p></div>");
// меняем текст у time
f.find("time").text(Date.now().toString());
// подключаем обработчик 
f.find("time").on("click", function () { alert(1); })
f.find("time").click(); // вызовется alert(1);
// выводим фрагмент на страницу
f.appendTo("body");
```

Comment: в вашем примере создаваемым элементам нельзя назначить обработчики события например.При создании конкретного элемента - можно

Comment: @Grundy _"нельзя назначить обработчики события"_ -- на основе jquery можно. добавил в ответ.

Comment: в вопросе нет ни слова о jQuery :-)

Comment: @Grundy  _"в вопросе нет ни слова о jQuery :)"_ -- бывает, что авторы вопросов не знают как можно сделать проще и придумывают 'велосипеды'. поэтому надо предлагать разные варианты.

Comment: не менее часто отвечающие не понимают, что именно спрашивает автор, и, как следствие, отвечают на какой-то свой, придуманный вопрос

Comment: @Grundy _"не менее часто отвечающие не понимают, что именно спрашивает автор, и, как следствие, отвечают на какой-то свой, придуманный вопрос"_ -- а вы понимаете? :) не вижу ваш ответ. но вижу минус. кстати, вопрос звучит так "Не могу создать фрагмент.". и если вы не придумываете ответы, то скажите, где в вопросе про события? :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34436/discussion-between-grundy-and-stack).